# DBDParams password escape

Tags: mysql, apache, parameters, connection

Here is the string I use to connect to MySql from Apache:

```
DBDParams "host=127.0.0.1,user=username,pass=complexpassword"
```

Problem is, the password has special chars like ?!()|.@^ and so on.

I already try to insert all the password into quote and double quote, and the same with the entire string. No quotes or double quotes into that.

I do I escape the chars?

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the special character with `URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`.

Then use the result as your parameters

Eg: `password@1234! -> password%401234%21`

Or you can manually construct the encoded version [with this reference](http://www.greentea.markschwing1.com/unico.html)

One another way to get the encoded version is open your browser console and try `encodeURIComponent()` method

Comment: Did you encode your password? And give a try to set default dbname like the example here `DBDParams host=localhost,dbname=pony,user=shetland,pass=appaloosa`

Comment: Yes, the complete string I used was `host=127.0.0.1,user=root,dbname=dbname,pass=<encoded_password>`

Comment: It seems that the char that is giving problems is the pipe...I tried to escape it as you said but nothing happens...

Comment: Pipe (`|`) will be encoded as (`%7C`). Did you use that? @DomenicoD'Attoma

Comment: Yes, it looked like the problem was the pipe. I encoded it as you said, but still nothing. I ended up removing the pipe from the password, even though several other chars were in it.